# session is not updated in signin method using firebase in nextjs

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, next-auth

I'm encountering issues with authentication in my Next.js application using NextAuth (v4) with Firebase. Below are snippets of my code:

##AuthOptions settings: This section contains the configuration settings for authentication using NextAuth. It includes the setup for various authentication providers such as Google and Yandex, as well as the Credentials provider for handling email/password authentication. Additionally, it specifies the FirestoreAdapter for integrating with Firebase Cloud Firestore and defines session callbacks for user session management.

##Form submission handling: Here, I have the code for processing form submissions, particularly from the sign-in form. It utilizes react-hook-form to retrieve and validate data on the client side. Upon successful submission, it redirects the user to the profile page.

##Protected profile page: This snippet represents the profile page that should only be accessible to authenticated users. It employs server-side session validation using getServerSession from NextAuth. If the session is invalid or nonexistent, the user is redirected to the sign-in page.

I'm having trouble understanding why the user isn't being redirected to the profile page after successful authentication. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

###Here are the authOptions settings:

```
import { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import YandexProvider from 'next-auth/providers/yandex';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { User, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { FirestoreAdapter } from '@auth/firebase-adapter';
import { Adapter } from 'next-auth/adapters';
import { cert } from 'firebase-admin/app';
import { app, auth, db } from '@/configs/firebaseConfig';
import { addUserToSessionCollections } from '@/serverActions/addUserToDB';

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_SECRET!,
    }),
    YandexProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_YANDEX_CIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_YANDEX_SECRET!,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials): Promise<User | null> {
        return await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          credentials.email || '',
          credentials.password || '',
        )
          .then(userCredential => {
            if (userCredential.user) {
              const accessToken = userCredential.user.stsTokenManager.accessToken;
              const refreshToken = userCredential.user.stsTokenManager.refreshToken;
              const email = userCredential.user.email;
              const userUid = userCredential.user.uid;
              let tokenExpire = Date.now() + 1 * 50000;
              return {
                user: {
                  uid: userUid,
                  token: accessToken,
                  refreshToken: refreshToken,
                  email: email,
                  tokenExpire: tokenExpire,
                } as User,
              };
            }
            return null;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Firebase authentication error:', error);
            throw new Error('Authentication failed');
          });
      },
    }),
  ],
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter({
    credential: cert({
      projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID!,
      clientEmail: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL!,
      privateKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY!.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    }),
  }),
  pages: {
    signIn: '/signin',
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    session({session, token, user}) {
      if (session && user) {
        session.user.id = user.id;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
};
```

###This is how I process data from the sign-in form. I use `react-hook-form` to retrieve and validate data on the client side.

```
const onSubmit = useCallback(async () => {
    const {email, password} = getValues();
    console.log(email, password);

    const response = await signIn('credentials', {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      redirect: false,
    });
    if (response && !response.error) {
      router.push('/profile');
    } else {
      setErrorModalOpen(true);
    }
  }, [getValues, router]);`
```

###And here's the profile page that's protected by server session validation:

```
import { authOptions } from '@/configs/authOptions';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export default async function Profile() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  console.log(session, 'PROFILE SESSIONS');
  if (!session) {
    return redirect('/signin');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Profile of {session?.user?.name}</h1>
      {session?.user?.image && <img src={session.user.image} alt='' />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I found a way to update my session via JWT, if you need a detailed description you can email me at pavl0ffn94@gmail.com and I will explain the whole process. you need to get the user and token into your token, then update the token fields and pass the updated token to the session.